# React-Native. Creating sliding animation

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create an animation that i can't figure out. Let's say i have a square (100x100)in the center of the view. I would like any length text to slide from the "behind" of it to the right side of view. Obviously i want the text not to be visible but only animation.

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 10):

Basically you need to set your animated x value to -(width of your square), so in this case -100, and set a dynamic style to an Animated.View. The trick is just calling an animation handled by Animation.spring (but you could use Animation.timing or any of the methods offered by the [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html)) and setting transform: [{translateX: myAnimatedValue}].

It's really not that different from CSS3 transforms. You have an element off-canvas and you gradually make it visible to the user.
I hope this could be useful.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';

// const styles = ...

export default class SlidingExample extends Component {

  state = {
    visible: false,
    x: new Animated.Value(-100),
  };

  slide = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.state.x, {
      toValue: 0,
    }).start();
    this.setState({
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  render() {
    // in practice you wanna toggle this.slide() after some props validation, I hope
    this.slide();
    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.slideView, {
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: this.state.x
              }
            ]
          }]}
        >
          {/* your content, such as this.props.children */}
        </Animated.View>
      </View>;
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What would be in styles.SlideView? Style of an animation or style of a sliding element?

Comment: Style of the sliding element, like backgroundColor or stuff like that.

Comment: I am really new to React Native and i struggle. I am trying to use it like this but i get  error " argument 0 (NSNumber) of UIManager must be not null: render(){
   this.slide();
   return (
    <View>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { transform: [{ translateX: this.state.x}]}]}>

      <Text>test</Text>

  </Animated.View>
    </View>

   );
 }

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Man :)